# I see no splash screen or output on one specific monitor

Tags: display, raspbian-wheezy

...using raspbian wheezy edition (the original back when it was new and sid was the only alternative), a 32" HD tv and a little 7" HD tv

**THE PROBLEM**

With the little 7" hdmi tv, this one SD card install boots but i can not see any text on the screen.  I know it boots fine because I can SSH into it and I can plug it into the 32" tv (which is how I normally use it) and I can see the splash screen and console output fine.

I have a second SD card with the same install of wheezy and if I plug it into the 7" tv it boots as expected(I can see the color splash screen and the console output as debian comes alive).

Once again my problem is that this one SD card boots fine, but i can not see any output when I plug it into a little 7" hdmi... its as if wheezy thinks its still using the 1920x1080 resolution and Im only able to see a small portion of the screen. I've been tinkering with the config settings for console fonts as I'm getting older and that little give me a headache.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you just tried copying the `config.txt` file from the working card to the other? If that doesn't fix it it's probably a firmware issue. Copy `start.elf`, `bootcode.bin`, and `fixup.dat` from the working card to the other one to test it out. (Making a backup before copying is recommended.)

Comment: I'll try when I get home. what does config.txt contain. The others "sound" like compiled files: remember that I can ssh into the **"non-working"** card and it works swimmingly when hooked to another monitor.

Comment: config.txt contains configuration parameters including parameters that control which video is used and how video is used. See http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video for more details.

Comment: "probably a firmware issue" related to the later versions of the image (remember that i was still running the old wheezy). anyhow the fix was to uncomment #hdmi_safe=1